# static lifetime in closures of threads in rust

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

```
use std::thread;
fn main() {
   // static NUMBERS: [i32;3] = [1,2,3];
   let numbers = vec![1,2,3];

    thread::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(move ||{
            for n in &numbers {
                println!("{n}");
            }
        });
        s.spawn(move ||{
            println!("length, {}", numbers.len());
        });
    });

for n in numbers{
    println!("{n}");
}

}
```

why does this particular code give error but use of NUMBER(commented section) does not give error?
I understand why the numbers would give error because the ownership of the number is moved to the first thread, but shouldn't the same issue be observed when using the static NUMBERS, because from what I understand of the static lifetime,it just means that any reference to NUMBERS can live to the end of the program.

I expected the code to not work with the static NUMBERS too but the code works just fine

Comment: `static` items and the `'static` lifetime are related, but they are very different concepts.

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned, a `static` variable is valid for the lifetime of the program. It is essentially read only and since you are accessing it by reference, there is no issue. A mutable reference would require synchronization via interior mutability like a `Mutex`.

Another important thing to note is `static` items [cannot be moved](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.static.html).

EDIT: If you do not have `move` closures, you can borrow the value.